# 403 Forbidden page Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I can't seem to find the 403 error problem, when I send a JSON request to register in Postman I get the 403 Forbidden error with no message.
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYOZn.png)

**SecureConfig.Java**

This is the configuration file.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**AuthConroller**

This is the controller of the project to authenticate, when I sign up the new user was added to the database successfully, it sends afterwards a mail verification to the fake mail using Mailtrap " https://mailtrap.io " . But when I request to receive the authentication token and the username I receive the error.

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/auth", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest ) {
        authService.signup(registerRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User's Registration was successful", HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @GetMapping("accountVerification/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyAccount(@PathVariable String token){
        authService.verifyAccount(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Account created successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        return authService.login(loginRequest);

    }

}
```

**AuthService**

This is the autentication service.

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;
    private final MailService mailService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;


    public void signup(RegisterRequest registerRequest){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(registerRequest.getUsername());
        user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setEnabled(false);
        user.setCreated(Instant.now());
        userRepository.save(user);

        String token = generetedVerificationToken(user);
        mailService.sendMail(new NotificationEmail("Please " +
                "Activate Your Account", user.getEmail(), "Thanks " +
                "for signing up. Click on the link below to go home: " +
                "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/accountVerification/" + token));
    }
    private String generetedVerificationToken(User user){
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken();
        verificationToken.setToken(token);
        verificationToken.setUser(user);

        verificationTokenRepository.save(verificationToken);
        return token;

    }

    public void verifyAccount(String token) {
        Optional<VerificationToken> verificationToken = verificationTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
        fetchUserAndEnable(verificationToken.orElseThrow(() -> new SpringRedditException("Invalid Token")));

    }

    private void fetchUserAndEnable(VerificationToken verificationToken){
        String username = verificationToken.getUser().getUsername();
        Optional<org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User> v = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        UserDetails user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new SpringRedditException("User not found with name - " + username));
        User s = (User) user;
        s.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(s);

    }

    public String encodePassword(String password) { return passwordEncoder.encode(password);}

    public String login(LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginRequest.getUsername(),
                loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return jwtProvider.generatedToken(authentication);
    }
}
```

**JwtProvider**

This class is to generate the tokens for each user. I didn't use the JKS I've found in the tutoriel, because it provides an error.

```java
@Service
public class JwtProvider {

//    private KeyStore keyStore;
    private Key key;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);
    }
        public String generatedToken(Authentication authentication){
            org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User principal =
                    (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(principal.getUsername())
                    .signWith(key)
                    .compact();
        }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

Here goes the implementation that gives the user authority to connect :

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)  {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user" +
                "with username : " + username));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true,
                true, true,
                getAuthorities("USER"));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role){
        return singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
}
```

and last

**AutheticationResponse**

In the DTO file we have this class in order to receive the authenticatonToken and the username in postman as a JSON format.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationResponse {
    private String authenticationToken;
    private String username;
}
```

After adding `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to `application.properties` file, I managed to see the reason this error appears in the below image.

[Debug results Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hEFq.png)

Comment: Do you send Authorization header in your request?

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov Yes I did, I;; add the section along

Comment: and what will happen if you'll try without it?

Comment: I won't be able to save the user's details, as you can see, in the tutorial, I had to use a userRepository class to save the details of the user.

```

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User> findByUsername(String username);
}

```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you followed, please? Also, have a look at the [JWT sample in spring-security-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login).

Comment: Sure, here is the link and the github repository for the backend. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKlTBBuc32c  .  https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/spring-reddit-clone  . Thanks for the link. @SteveRiesenberg

Comment: it is probably CORS, and if you enable spring security debug logs it will tell you exactly why you are getting a 403.

Comment: Thanks @Haru, that is a really popular tutorial. However, as of Spring Security 5.x, I recommend starting with the sample I linked above and building from there instead of following that tutorial. Spring Security 5 now has built-in support for JWTs as Bearer tokens, and it's fairly easy to use Nimbus or JJWT or any other library you prefer for generating JWTs.

Comment: Thank you @Toerktumlare, now I can see the problems I have.

Comment: i completly agree with @SteveRiesenberg that tutorial, is teaching some bad practices, for instance storing JWTs in local storage, and the implementation of custom security. As steve points out, spring security has full JWT support, with a customizable JWTFilter already implemented into the framework.

Comment: I see, thanks @Toerktumlare Steve Riesenberg I'll take your advice and see the right way to do the  of custom security implementation and JWT.

Comment: it is all documented quite clearly in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Comment: @Toerktumlare  and Steve, I am the creator of the video tutorial, I completely agree with the points you raised and I will plan an update to the tutorial and also will plan to update the source code.